# is there a way to connect to mysql using oracle sqlplus instant client

Tags: mysql, oracle, sqlplus

i am stuck while trying to connect to mysql using sqlplus client and i have already asked this question at `askubuntu.com` as

https://askubuntu.com/questions/674871/not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-oracle-sqlplus-instant-client-in-ubun

please any one help me.. trying to solve it from last 5 hours :(

Comment: What does this question have to do with Ubuntu?  Would be helpful if rather than specifying how long you have been working on it, what you have tried

Comment: Is it possible?  Maybe.  Why would you want to?  Ancient versions of `SQL*Plus` had the ability to use generic ODBC DSNs to connect to non-Oracle databases.  That was a horrible thing to do and basically no one ever did it.  If memory serves, they removed the functionality at some point because it was such a poor idea.  MySQL has its own command line utilities that work very well with MySQL.  Why wouldn't you want to use those?

Comment: @Justin sir , thanks for your important time, I was just trying to connect it because one of my friends ask me to do this for him, but you are very right why to use MySQL why not do it using Oracle database

Comment: Why does your friend want to use Oracle's command-line utility to connect to a MySQL database?  I have to believe that your friend really wants to use `SQL*Plus` to connect to an Oracle database and/or the MySQL client utilities to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: @JustinCave Sir, he is saying that he have sqlplus 9.x version which he use to connect with MySQL database on windows xp and want me to set it up on Ubuntu for him, that's why I am looking for it.. But not found anything except your meaningful comment...

Comment: The functionality might have existed some time back in the 9.x days (though ODBC on linux adds some extra complexity).  That version of Oracle has been desupported for a long time so it's not going to be publicly available.  You'd need to log a support ticket with Oracle (which assumes you have an active support contract).  And it almost certainly won't be supported on any vaguely recent version of Linux.  You'd have to be installing a version of Linux from back when 9i was supported which is probably roughly a decade ago.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks a lot sir, now I will set it up using latest oracle database at least he can able to run his commands and do his practice.. Thanks a lot sir for your important time...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is, no, you cannot connect to MySQL using the current oracle instant client.

Comment: thanks for your important time sir, @JustinCave sir already explained me that and now i am using Oracle 11g express edition and its working perfect with oracle sql client in ubuntu x64 15.04 :) and i am also learning it along with my friend..